# I want to recall my Deck class inside the method to shuffle to restore the deck before shuffling so that i dont shuffle a deck with less than 52 cards

Tags: python, class, oop

Ok guys I'm doing a Deck class and I want to make my deck so that when card are dealt, I can restore the deck when shuffling. I thought that it could work recalling the class with the same class name but python raise "TypeError: restore_deck() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
        values = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
        self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in suits for value in values]


    def shuffle(self):
        def restore_deck(self):
            self = Deck()
        if self.count() < 52: # |here is the problem!
            restore_deck(self)# |
        shuffle(self.cards)
        return self
```

Comment: It's ok even doing the restore function outside of the shuffle method but i can't do that either

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you mean you remove cards from the list of cards in Deck and what you would like to do is shuffle all 52 cards, to do this what we can do is import the module random and when we would like to shuffle the cards we can just recreate the list of cards then shuffle the full list. I added repr method just so you could see output clearly. If you would not like to regenerate the whole list you could instead store the cards "removed" and add them back into the list before shuffling.

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.suit, self.value))


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"]
        self.values = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',' 7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
        self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in self.suits for value in self.values]

    def shuffle(self):
        self.cards = [Card(value, suit) for suit in self.suits for value in self.values]
        random.shuffle(self.cards)


d = Deck()
print(d.cards)
d.shuffle()
print(d.cards)
```